# Drupal 8 - Unable to upgrade to latest version via composer

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php

My current Drupal Version: 8.7.8. Want to upgrade to 8.8.0.

I already run

```
composer update
composer prohibits drupal/core:8.8.0

drupal/core    8.8.0  requires          typo3/phar-stream-wrapper (^3.1.3)              
drupal/drupal  -      requires          typo3/phar-stream-wrapper (^2.1.1)              
drupal/core    8.8.0  requires          doctrine/annotations (^1.4)                     
drupal/drupal  -      does not require  doctrine/annotations (but v1.2.7 is installed)
```

So I run

```
composer update drupal/core typo/* doctrine/* --with-dependencies
```

It gives

```
Package "drupal/core" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Package "typo/*" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/sdboyer/gliph%24a386760768df0346abad1d5c7e9e8dcf3eba1dd5aaa86a30ddc548504b0fffa0.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Operation timed out
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                              
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/sdboyer/gliph%24a386760768df0346abad1d5c7e9e8dcf3eba1dd5aaa86a30ddc548504b0fffa0.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: geta  
  ddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known                                                                                                                          
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

On

```
composer outdated drupal/*
```

It gives

```
drupal/admin_toolbar 1.27.0 2.0.0 Provides a drop-down menu interface to the core Drupal Toolbar.
```

So I tried

```
composer update "drupal/admin_toolbar:^2.0"
Package "drupal/admin_toolbar:^2.0" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package drupal/admin_toolbar (locked at 1.27.0, required as ^2.0) is satisfiable by drupal/admin_toolbar[1.27.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I also delete `composer.lock` file `vendor` folder & run the `composer clearcache` then `composer install` command.

I am not sure what is causing the issue to upgrade.

Comment: Why are you using composer update drupal/core typo and not composer update drupal/core typo3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into your `composer.json` which basic requirements are set.
I think you have some very specific versions where a range would help.

Set new version(range)s explicit from command line or in json (of course save your old file). It's easier to set/update multiple versions in the file than by command line.

Also  it might help to use the option `--with-dependencies` to update multiple packages in one run.

Then you have help with
`composer update --dry-run` which will tell you what will happen and with
`composer why-not <packet>[:<version>]` which tells you why a packet (in version ...) can't be installed.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting your /vendor folder and reinstall.

According to Help docs, there are some new issues that may pop up when upgrading by composer 8.8.0 and above.

[Update core via Composer - Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer#s-special-considerations-for-upgrading-to-drupal-880-and-later)

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. The question was how to **upgrade** versions. Removing the vendor folder and reinstall all packages does not use more recent packages than those installed before